# Go http.Client. Why the elapsed time is so big?

Tags: go

I have a code like this. To be short, I'm creating the http client with a timeout and doing some request to some server.

```
package rtb

import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var tcpHttpClient *http.Client

func init() {
    tcpHttpClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Millisecond * 200,
    }
}

func doRequest(url string, reqBody []byte) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(reqBody))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // This line returns an error
    resp, clientError := tcpHttpClient.Do(req)
    
    // ...
}
```

The problem is, sometimes the elapsed time is a WAY lot bigger than the timeout itself. And I can't understand why.

Example: The request has not succeeded with the error message "context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)".
The timeout of the client is **200ms**, but the elapsed time is **3 seconds**. As far as I know, the Client.Timeout should cover all the way from the dial to the getting the response body.

So, why the elapsed time is bigger than the timeout? Why the request has not been cancelled earlier?

Comment: Look. You presented code but that code looks okay but doesn't work. You cannot make a request to "some_url". Thus nobody can reproduce your problem. Also your problem description is "sometimes". That just is too vague. If this is an issue for you you either have to come up with runable code that reproduces this issue or you have to ask on golang-nuts or open an bug report.

Comment: It's just a dummy url, I'm not an idiot :-)

Comment: "dummy url" doesn't make it reproducible either. Can you reproduce the problem if you set up a local server, that just idles after receiving the post request?

Comment: No I can't (I tried it, of course). That's why I'm here. It's very rare situation, but I'd like to understand why it theoretically can happen. If no one knows, then probably you can't help me.

Comment: That would mean the timeout setting *works in principle* but maybe the net is evil... Is it a specific server that's causing the unexpected "over-timeout-time"? Did you try to have a look what's going on on the TCP level, e.g. with Wireshark?

Comment: Well, like I said, it's a very seldom issue, so it's very difficult to catch. It happens with a couple of servers, I'll try to dig more in that direction. You probably right, it can be a network issue. I just thought the Client.Timeout is solid and can't be exceeded at all (at least not that much).

Comment: I think the question is clear without any specific URL and can be answered. I vote for reopen.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell and very simplified: There is a lot happening when a computer makes an HTTP request. There is no timer running in parallel that constantly checks the timeout and cancels the HTTP request as soon as possible. But between all necessary steps there is a check if the timeout is exceeded. When the timeout is exceeded, the system starts to cancel the request and does other cleanup tasks. In your case the first check that noticed that the timeout was exceeded happened after three seconds.

So it might take much longer than the specified timeout until the error is returned, but the given limit is respected.

As a side note: When making a lot of asynchronous tasks that are out of your control (like doing an HTTP request over a network) go routines can be used to unblock your main routine.